# Need a SSR friendly way to render HTML in VueJS3

Tags: html, vuejs3, server-side-rendering

i have an api that delivers texts for my vuejs create webpage, and i use `<div v-if="text" v-html="text">` to render the html.

i have put the `$fetch()` inside `onMounted()`. The text is being displayed, but sadly not in the source code.

I cant find a SSR friendly way to render the html although it's badly needed for Google and SEO.

Thanks Adrian

Answer (score 0):

this made it work in the end

```
<template>
 <div class="text" v-if="text" v-html="text"></div>
</template>
```

```
<script setup>
const {data: text} = await useFetch('/api/texts', {
    params: {
        url: 'xxx',
    }
});
...
```

its part of the sources. Nuxt rocks